# How to query DynamoDB by Hash and Range Key in java?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm quite new `DynamoDB` sdk. I don't really know how can you query in a table in DynamoDB with the hashKey and rangeKey.

Table schema:

```
1. Id (HK)
2. Book (GSI HK)
3. User (GSI RK)
```

I'm using global secondary index `GSI: bookAndUserIndex`.
Code snippet:

```
    public Loan getByBookAndUser(String book, String user) {
        Loan loan = null;
        HashMap<String, AttributeValue> av = new HashMap<>();
        av.put(":v1", new AttributeValue().withS(book));
        DynamoDBQueryExpression<Loan> queryExp = new DynamoDBQueryExpression<Loan>()
                .withIndexName("bookAndUserIndex")
                .withKeyConditionExpression("book = :v1")
                .withExpressionAttributeValues(av)
                .withConsistentRead(false);
        PaginatedQueryList<Loan> result = this.mapper.query(Loan.class, queryExp);
        if (result.size() > 0) {
            loan = result.get(0);
        }
        return loan;
    }
```

How can I edit this code to filter/get also by `user`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add the range (sort) key to the expression:

```
   public Loan getByBookAndUser(String book, String user) {
        Loan loan = null;
        HashMap<String, AttributeValue> av = new HashMap<>();
        av.put(":v1", new AttributeValue().withS(book));
        av.put(":user", new AttributeValue().withS(user));
        DynamoDBQueryExpression<Loan> queryExp = new DynamoDBQueryExpression<Loan>()
                .withIndexName("bookAndUserIndex")
                .addExpressionAttributeNamesEntry("#user", "user")
                .withKeyConditionExpression("book = :v1 AND #user = :user")
                .withExpressionAttributeValues(av)
                .withConsistentRead(false);
        PaginatedQueryList<Loan> result = this.mapper.query(Loan.class, queryExp);
        if (result.size() > 0) {
            loan = result.get(0);
        }
        return loan;
    }
```

This is well documented in the [AWS SDK for Java documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/model/QueryRequest.html#withKeyConditionExpression-java.lang.String-).

Comment: When I try to run it, it throws: ```com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.AmazonDynamoDBException: Invalid KeyConditionExpression: Attribute name is a reserved keyword; reserved keyword: user```

Comment: @wild_tola then you'll have to also use an expression attribute name. See my updated answer.

Comment: TY! also, point a small typo, this should be like this  ```.addExpressionAttributeNamesEntry("#user", "user")```. TY yet again!